# Problema para detectar usuario de dominio en asp core 2

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, webapi

Buenos días.

Estoy teniendo problemas para poder autentificar a un usuario de dominio en asp core 2 para poder manipular directorios.

El entorno cliente es una aplicación angular 4, servidor web api asp Core (c#) y server windows 7 para archivo compartidos.

la idea es que el cliente suba una imagen y mediante el web api alojarla en el serve compartido.

para que la web api manipule el directorio y el file, necesita la credencial de un usuario de dominio con permiso de escritura.

- Existe la posibilidad de enviar del cliente al web api las credenciales del usuario logueado para poder implementar:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Existe la posibilidad de dar permiso con un usuario "X" cada vez que se haga una petición en el web api?.

Hilos vistos.

[Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth)

[docs.microsoft.com WindowsIdentity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906220(v=vs.110).aspx)

espero haberme expresado adecuadamente.

Answer (score 0):

solucione el problema de credencial que necesitaba la web api para poder manipular los directorios y files en un servidor compartido.

https://jcifs.samba.org/